# How to get a bold wide tilde?

Tags: math-mode, bold, tilde

If I type

```
\boldmath $\widetilde T$\unboldmath
```

I get
[image: widetilde T]
where unfortunately the tilde above the T is a little flimsy for my taste. 
Is there a better way to do this?
I found a paper that has something, that appears a little bolder, in it. [image: bigger tilde]

Comment: You are not using bm in that fragment (although bm would give the same) the default computer modern font set doesn't have a bold extension font so the wide tilde comes from cmex5 in both cases.

Answer (score 5):

There is a bold version of `cmex` nowadays:

```
\documentclass{article}

\DeclareFontShape{OMX}{cmex}{m}{b}{<-> cmexb10}{}
\SetSymbolFont{largesymbols}{bold}{OMX}{cmex}{m}{b}

\usepackage{amsmath,bm}

\begin{document}

$\widetilde{T}$ $\bm{\widetilde{T}}$

$\widetilde{TU}$ $\bm{\widetilde{TU}}$

\end{document}
```

[image]

In order to make it as a self-standing symbol, you can define a new symbol font:

```
\documentclass{article}

\DeclareFontShape{OMX}{cmex}{m}{b}{<-> cmexb10}{}

\usepackage{amsmath,bm}

\DeclareSymbolFont{boldlargesymbols}{OMX}{cmex}{m}{b}
\DeclareMathAccent{\bwidetilde}{\mathord}{boldlargesymbols}{"65}

\begin{document}

$\widetilde{(ab\mid cd)}=
(ab\mid\widetilde{\,cd\,})+(\widetilde{ab}\mid cd)-
(\widetilde{ab}\mid\widetilde{cd})$

$\bwidetilde{(ab\mid cd)}=
(ab\mid\bwidetilde{\,cd\,})+(\bwidetilde{ab}\mid cd)-
(\bwidetilde{ab}\mid\bwidetilde{cd})$

\end{document}
```

There is also a trick to force a wider version.

[image]

On the other hand, if you want Times-like fonts, `newtxmath` already has a bold version of the math extension font.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{newtxmath,newtxtext}

\DeclareSymbolFont{boldlargesymbols}{LMX}{ntxexx}{b}{n}
\DeclareMathAccent{\bwidetilde}{\mathord}{boldlargesymbols}{"65}

\begin{document}

$\widetilde{(ab\mid cd)}=
(ab\mid\widetilde{cd})+(\widetilde{ab}\mid cd)-
(\widetilde{ab}\mid\widetilde{cd})$

$\bwidetilde{(ab\mid cd)}=
(ab\mid\bwidetilde{cd})+(\bwidetilde{ab}\mid cd)-
(\bwidetilde{ab}\mid\bwidetilde{cd})$

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: For anyone that cares, the bold tilde generated by the first code block of this answer does appear pixelated under zoom in my PDF output (while other symbols do not).  Nonetheless, a very helpful answer.

Comment: @SapereAude You possibly have a problem with font maps and you should try to regenerate them. MiKTeX?

Comment: Yes, MiKTeX 2.9.  Any tips on how to proceed?  Searches for "regenerating font maps in LaTeX" are turning up little useful information.  (Sorry if this is elementary.)

Answer (score 4):

I'm afraid you hit on something that can't be easily solved. Here for comparison all possible solutions for making math stuff bold and then a handmade bold tilde T:

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{amsbsy}
\usepackage{bm}
\usepackage{fixmath}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\begin{document}
% not bold
$\widetilde T$
% not bold enough either
$\mathbf{\widetilde T}$
$\pmb{\widetilde T}$
\boldmath$\widetilde T$
$\boldsymbol{\widetilde T}$
$\bm{\widetilde T}$
$\mathbold{\widetilde T}$
% maybe even crayons would be easier and prettier but well ...
\raisebox{.7em}{\resizebox{.6em}{!}{\ensuremath{\bm{\sim}}}}\hspace{-.7em}$T$
\end{document}
```

[image]

Using .8em in the raisebox will be about the same height as the other tildes but I personally liked it better this way. I'm not saying it's pretty and I'm not saying it's easy :/

Answer (score 3):

Some approachs:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx,xcolor}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\begin{document}
\boldmath $\widetilde{T}$\unboldmath 
\color{blue!50!black} ~
% require graphicx
\resizebox{.8em}{1.1em}{\boldmath $\displaystyle \widetilde{\scriptstyle T}$\unboldmath}
% ooaling solution
\boldmath \ooalign{$\textstyle\widetilde{\phantom{W}}$\cr\hidewidth$T$\hidewidth\cr} \boldmath
% require mathtools
\boldmath $\mathrlap{\widetilde{\phantom{W}}}\,T$\unboldmath 
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 0):

When the tilde doesn't need to be wide you can use `$\bm{\thicksim}$`, with the `bm` and `amssymb` packages.