# double tilde symbol under letter

Tags: stacking-symbols, tensor

Currently, I'm representing second and fourth order tensor with this (taken from someone, and i don't really get how it works):

```
    % tensor 2:
    \newcommand{\tend}[1]{\oalign{\mbox{\boldmath$#1$}\crcr\hidewidth$\scriptscriptstyle\sim$\hidewidth}}
    %tensor 4:
    \newcommand{\tenq}[1]{\tend{\tend #1}\vphantom{#1}}
```

Which looks like this:
[image: tensors]

I very much don't like the result: boldface is strange, with scales badly, there is too much spacing for the fourth order tensor... I found the untertilde package, with looks more robust for second order, but i cannot see how to make 4th order from it.
I also found this topic, [bold widetilde](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/99934/how-to-get-a-bold-wide-tilde), which doe not adress symbol stacking for 4th order.

Is there a simple elegant way to do? My main concern here is consistant boldface for the tilde and the letter, and proper vertical spacing of the 4th order.

Thanks

Comment: Can you clarify what you want: everything bold, nothing bold,...? `\oalign` is a plain TeX command for building minature tables, used for stacking symbols.  `\crcr` indicates a newline.  `\hidewdith...\hidewidth` disguises the width of the intervening material.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here I use stacks to recursively place `\sim` under the argument, based on the value of the optional argument.  In the definition, the `[1pt]` is the under-gap from the argument and the `[0pt]` is the vertical separation between `\sim` characters in a multi-stack.  These values can be altered to suit (including being made negative).

I have not used any bold font for the tensor itself, though it could be added, if desired, to the definition, or at time of invocation.

The specification of `\def\useanchorwidth{T}` says to ignore the width of the `\sim` underset in setting the horizontal spacing.  The only time that could be an issue is if you, for example, used adjacent invocations on narrow arguments, e.g., `\tenq[2]{i}\tenq[3]{j}`.  While the `\useanchorwidth` line could be removed, in which case `\tenq` with narrow arguments would always take up at least the width of a `\scriptscriptstyle\sim`,  my first step would instead be to manually add `\,` space on those very rare occasions when needed.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{stackengine}
\stackMath
\newcommand\tenq[2][1]{%
 \def\useanchorwidth{T}%
  \ifnum#1>1%
    \stackunder[0pt]{\tenq[\numexpr#1-1\relax]{#2}}{\scriptscriptstyle\sim}%
  \else%
    \stackunder[1pt]{#2}{\scriptscriptstyle\sim}%
  \fi%
}
\begin{document}
\[
\tenq{\sigma}\neq\tenq[2]{\Lambda}\neq\tenq[3]{\Delta}\neq\tenq[4]{\psi}
\]

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 12):

If you like the first one, you can use the same definition for `\tenq` but using `\approx` instead of `\sim`.

Also use `\bm` from the same package instead of `\boldmath`.

MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath,bm}

% tensor 2:
\newcommand{\tend}[1]{\hbox{\oalign{$\bm{#1}$\crcr\hidewidth$\scriptscriptstyle\bm{\sim}$\hidewidth}}}
%tensor 4:
\newcommand{\tenq}[1]{\hbox{\oalign{$\bm{#1}$\crcr\hidewidth$\scriptscriptstyle\bm{\approx}$\hidewidth}}}

\begin{document}

\[
\tend{\sigma}\neq\tenq{\Lambda}
\]

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I'd put `\m@th` into the `$...$` to remove any non-zero `\mathsurround`.

Comment: thanks for this answer! Yours and Steven's are very much ok, but I'll accept Steven's for consistancy of the tilde notation and modularity.

Answer (score 0):

Just for fun.

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{amsmath,bm}

\newlength{\fillwidth}
% creates a tilde which slightly overlaps what's above and below, centered in a space  \fillwidth wide
\newcommand{\flatsim}{\hbox to \fillwidth{\hfil\raisebox{0pt}[.05ex][.05ex]{$\scriptscriptstyle\bm{\sim}$}\hfil}}


\newcommand{\triple}[1]{\settowidth{\fillwidth}{$\bm{#1}$}%
  \vtop{\baselineskip=0pt\hbox{$\bm{#1}$}\hbox{\rule{0pt}{.2ex}}\flatsim\flatsim\flatsim}}

\begin{document}
\triple{\sigma}
\end{document}
```

[image: triple tilde]