# Double-tilde over symbol

Tags: math-mode, accents, tilde

I am trying to get a double tilde symbol over a letter but I can't find a well suiting solution. I tried

```
$\tilde{\tilde{z}}$
```

and

```
$\overset{\approx}{z}$
```

but both solution look a bit off.
I am trying to find something with less vertical space between the two tildes but a similar size like `\tilde{}`.

*edit:* vertical spacing

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE. Have you tried loading the `amsmath` package?

Comment: Thank you! Yes, the problem is not that this solutions do not work,  they just look really bad.

Comment: If you do load this package, you *will* get proper-looking double tildes. That's why I asked if you'd tried it.

Comment: Yeah sry that is true. I meant the vertical spacing. I changed it in the original question.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

One of these?

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{calc}

\usepackage{accents}
\newcommand{\dbtilde}[1]{\accentset{\approx}{#1}}
\newcommand{\vardbtilde}[1]{\tilde{\raisebox{0pt}[0.85\height]{$\tilde{#1}$}}}

\begin{document}

    \[ \vardbtilde{z}\quad \dbtilde{z} \]%

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you! The solution using the `calc`package looks really great in my case.

Comment: Actually, I don't use it.  It was used in a first try that didn't work at well as the others I posted.

Comment: The `calc` solution doesn't scale properly in fractions.

Answer (score 13):

A variation on my answer here: [double tilde symbol under letter](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/229543/double-tilde-symbol-under-letter/229598#229598).  Here, `\tsup` takes an optional argument specifying the number of symbols to overset (default 2).

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{stackengine}
\stackMath
\newcommand\tsup[2][2]{%
 \def\useanchorwidth{T}%
  \ifnum#1>1%
    \stackon[-.5pt]{\tsup[\numexpr#1-1\relax]{#2}}{\scriptscriptstyle\sim}%
  \else%
    \stackon[.5pt]{#2}{\scriptscriptstyle\sim}%
  \fi%
}
\begin{document}
\[
\tsup[1]{z}\neq\tsup{\Lambda}\neq\tsup[3]{\Delta}\neq\tsup[4]{\psi}
\]

\end{document}
```

[image]

Here's a version that uses the proper tilde glyph and works across 10-12pt fontsize range:

```
\documentclass[10pt]{article}
\usepackage{stackengine}
\stackMath
\newcommand\tsup[2][2]{%
 \def\useanchorwidth{T}%
  \ifnum#1>1%
    \stackon[-1.3ex]{\tsup[\numexpr#1-1\relax]{#2}}{\mathchar"307E}%
  \else%
    \stackon[-1ex]{#2}{\mathchar"307E}%
  \fi%
}
\begin{document}
\[
\tilde z=\tsup[1]{z}\neq\tsup{\Lambda}\neq\tsup[3]{\Delta}\neq\tsup[4]{\psi}
\]
\fontsize{12pt}{14pt}\selectfont
\[
\tilde z=\tsup[1]{z}\neq\tsup{\Lambda}\neq\tsup[3]{\Delta}\neq\tsup[4]{\psi}
\]
\end{document}
```

[image]

In both MWE's the only issue missing is the italic kerning of the overset.  That could be somewhat addressed globally (not for each particular character) with a little `\kern`

```
\newcommand\tsup[2][2]{%
 \def\useanchorwidth{T}%
  \ifnum#1>1%
    \stackon[-1.3ex]{\tsup[\numexpr#1-1\relax]{#2}}{\mathchar"307E\kern-.5pt}%
  \else%
    \stackon[-1ex]{#2}{\mathchar"307E\kern-.5pt}%
  \fi%
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 8):

The `tipa` package has `\doubletilde`. However, it is not made for math mode, so you have to cheat a bit:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage[extra]{tipa}

\begin{document}

$\doubletilde{\kern-1pt$z$}$

\end{document}
```

[image]